# I can't install the gem json (1.6.3)

Tags: json

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /Users/..../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/danieljreardon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/json-1.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/danieljreardon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out

I'm very new to development, so any simple instructions and advice would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which operation system are you running?

Answer (score 3):

Install XCode from your Mac OS X DVD or Mac App Store.

Comment: New solution: get your *skinny* installer from here, if you have Lion or Snow Leopard. Apple approved. ~200MB. https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Answer (score 0):

Try install libgmp3-dev should solve this problem:

`sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`

credit: https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253